# why json.Unmarshal change the pointer value after append a new one in golang?

Tags: json, go, pointers, struct, unmarshalling

I have a question about why json.Unmarshal change the pointer value **(create_at)** first (**test1**) after append a new one (**test2**) but **num** is dont change in golang ?

json.Unmarshal will reuse the address ? I don't understand why append a new value (don't pointer value) will influences the elements insert before, if I change the *time.Time -> time.Time, this problem will be solve...

```
package main

import (
    "bytes"
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
    "time"
)

type test struct {
    Num      int        `json:"num"`
    CreateAt *time.Time `json:"create_at"`
}

func main() {

    var icr []test
    var res test

    now := time.Now()
    next := time.Now().Add(time.Hour)

    test1 := test{
        Num:      1,
        CreateAt: &now,
    }

    test2 := test{
        Num:      2,
        CreateAt: &next,
    }

    newBytes := new(bytes.Buffer)
    json.NewEncoder(newBytes).Encode(test1)

    json.Unmarshal(newBytes.Bytes(), &res)

    icr = append(icr, res)

    fmt.Println(PrettyPrint(icr))
    // [
    //   {
    //     "num": 1,
    //     "create_at": "2020-09-24T15:03:00.755169076+08:00"
    //   }
    // ]

    newBytes = new(bytes.Buffer)
    json.NewEncoder(newBytes).Encode(test2)

    json.Unmarshal(newBytes.Bytes(), &res)

    icr = append(icr, res)

    fmt.Println(PrettyPrint(icr))
    // [
    //   {
    //     "num": 1,
    //     "create_at": "2020-09-24T16:03:00.755169556+08:00"
    //   },
    //   {
    //     "num": 2,
    //     "create_at": "2020-09-24T16:03:00.755169556+08:00"
    //   }
    // ]
}

// PrettyPrint ...
func PrettyPrint(data interface{}) string {
    var out bytes.Buffer
    b, _ := json.Marshal(data)
    json.Indent(&out, b, "", "  ")
    return out.String()
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**The short version**: all elements in your slice are shallow copies of `res`, so the `CreateAt` field points to the same value.

**Details**:

When appending `res` to `icr`, the element added to `icr` is a copy of `res`.

This works fine for the field `Num`, it can be modified in `res` without impacting the data stored in `icr`. This is because it's a base type.

However, the `CreateAt` field of `res` **is a pointer**, so the copy is still the same pointer. All elements of `icr` will have `CreateAt` point to the same value. Any modification of that value will be reflected in all elements of `icr`.

You have two options (at least):

- change `CreateAt` to plain `time.Time`, meaning it will be copied and not just a pointer
- use a different variable to unmarshal the second time. eg: `json.Unmarshal(newBytes.Bytes(), &res2)`

Here is a clearer example without json or slices, just two variables one of which is a copy of the other: [see on playground](https://play.golang.org/p/Lk9ghiMkNFi):

```golang
package main

import (
    "bytes"
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
    "time"
)

type test struct {
    Num      int        `json:"num"`
    CreateAt *time.Time `json:"create_at"`
}

func main() {
    now := time.Now()
    res := test{1, &now}
    res2 := res

    fmt.Println(PrettyPrint(res), PrettyPrint(res2))
    
    // Modify res2:
    res2.Num = 2
    *res2.CreateAt = time.Now().Add(time.Hour)
    
    fmt.Println(PrettyPrint(res), PrettyPrint(res2))
}

// PrettyPrint ...
func PrettyPrint(data interface{}) string {
    var out bytes.Buffer
    b, _ := json.Marshal(data)
    json.Indent(&out, b, "", "  ")
    return out.String()
}
```

Output:

```
{
  "num": 1,
  "create_at": "2009-11-10T23:00:00Z"
} {
  "num": 1,
  "create_at": "2009-11-10T23:00:00Z"
}
{
  "num": 1,
  "create_at": "2009-11-11T00:00:00Z"
} {
  "num": 2,
  "create_at": "2009-11-11T00:00:00Z"
}
```

When updating `res2`, the `res2.Num` does not impact `res.Num` since it is a base type. However, `res2.CreateAt` and `res.CreateAt` both point to the same object so the change is reflected in both.